# IAR EWARM Unknown or ambiguous symbol __probeCmd in .dmac file

Tags: stm32, debugging, iar

When im  downloading and debugging my firmware to [STM32G070](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32g070cb.pdf) Nucleo board with IAR EWARM, im getting the following error message in the debug log, I tried researching about `__probeCmd` and `.dmac` files online, but couldn't gather any information.

[image: Debug log]

Im using ST-LINK onboard debugger connected via PC serial port for debugging and downloading. Even though this error appears i'm still able to download and debug the firmware without any issues. Have anyone encountered this issue.

Comment: This appears to be some library hiccup with this "dmac" file, whatever that is. If it's a file provided by IAR, I'd poke their support about it. Seems related to the specific in-circuit debugger. Missing drivers or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I add here that I have the same problem with IAR EWARM 8.32.4 and with the same .dmac file. Have you been able to manage it?

EDIT: after comparing the file with the version from preceding EWARM release 8.32.2, I figured out that the unwanted function `_ExecDeviceSetup()` has been wrongly added. Please remove exactly line interval 29-34 and line 36 (a matching `}`) and it will work.

Comment: @simonstar Not yet, I changed the debugger from STLink to J-Link

Comment: @simonstar you've added solution, which is good. But you left in the original "I am having same question", which confuses people. Please, edit this to make it into real answer.

Answer (score -1):

reinstall IAR9.3 will solve the problem

Comment: The original problem was solved already. I don't think a realistic answer to the problem is to reinstall something which you don't have yet, or must wait and buy when it is available.